# Efficient calculation of multiple rolling quantiles

Tags: r, performance, rolling-computation, quantile, processing-efficiency

From some other calculations I got a long vector with ~4500000 entries (`vec`). Now I'd like to calculate the 5th, 25th, 50th, 75th and 95th quantiles for a rolling `period = 1000`, i.e. I'd like to get these quantiles from 1st to 1000th element in `vec`, then for the 2nd to 1001th element in `vec`, etc.

Here is some example code and how I would have solved that problem:

```r
vec <- rnorm(4500000) #create sample data
res <- matrix(nrow=length(vec), ncol=5)
period = 1000
for (i in period:length(vec)) {
  res[i,] <- quantile(vec[(i-period+1):i], p=c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95))
}
```

(Although I used `rnorm` to create example data, my data is not normally distributed and the standard deviation is not constant!)

However, this implementation takes rather long. Thus, I'm looking for a more time-efficient implementation in R.

Comment: Are you looking only for exact solutions or are approximations also OK?

Comment: @user2974951 I'm looking for the exact solution. But how would you have done it with an approximation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the `runquantile` function from the `caTools` package. It did the job very fast.

Answer (score 2):

`roll_quantile` from the `roll` package is the fastest implementation.
works on matrices too.

https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/roll/html/roll_quantile.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sapply function:

```
res <- sapply(period:(length(vec)), function(x) quantile(vec[(x-period+1):x], p=c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)))
res <- t(res)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. However, benchmarking on a shorter vector shows me that it takes equally long to my loop solutions.

Comment: have you tried with rollapply? res <- rollapply(vec, period, function(x) quantile(x, p=c(0.05, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.95)), by = 1)

Comment: No, haven't tried it. But now I did - unfortunately still that slow ...